# how to set progress bar before spinner?

Tags: android

I have a alertdialog in which data coming from internet. Sometimes due to internet connectivity data comes late. so i want progress bar before spinner shows itself. while getting data i have written this.

```
final String[] List= new String{ 'abc', 'def'};
                ArrayList<String> ListArray = new ArrayList<String>();  
                ListArray.addAll(Arrays.asList(List));
                ListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, ListArray);  
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setTitle("Data");
                builder.setAdapter(ListAdapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                        txtExec.setText(ClientList[item]);
                    } 
                });
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();


ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
                dialog.setMessage("Please wait while loading...");
                dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
                dialog.setCancelable(true);
```

So how do i adjust progessDialog before alert dialog box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should load the data from the internet in a thread or an AsyncTask.

[here](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html) you have a small article describing the possibilities.

I recommend the [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) method, I post you a little pseudocode on how to do it, refer to the docs for more details on how you can pass the data you load in the `doInBackground` method to the `onPostExecute` for example.

```
private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        //setup and display the progressDialog
    }

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        //do your data loading
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void void) {
        //dismiss progress dialog and show the spinner
    }
}
```